# UnicodeDecodeError while using behave framework(1.2.5)

Tags: python, python-behave

I have multiple feature files each containing at least 5 scenarios(Test Cases).
To run all features using Behave Framework giving below command

```
behave --junit
```

I am getting following exception

```
Exception UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128) 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "myLoc/behave", line 9, in <module>
 load_entry_point('behave==1.2.5', 'console_scripts', 'behave')()
 File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 109, in main
 failed = runner.run()
 File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/runner.py", line 672, in run
 return self.run_with_paths()
 File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/runner.py", line 693, in run_with_paths
 return self.run_model()
File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/runner.py", line 483, in run_model
failed = feature.run(self)
File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/model.py", line 523, in run
failed = scenario.run(runner)
File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/model.py", line 882, in run
if not step.run(runner):
File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/model.py", line 1499, in run
output = runner.log_capture.getvalue()
File "project/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/log_capture.py", line 99, in getvalue
return '\n'.join(self.formatter.format(r) for r in self.buffer)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when this exception occurs, behave doesn't run next scenarios(Tests)

Can anyone help to fix this

Comment: Which version of Python are you using ? 0xe2 is probably an "â" encoded using latin-1, BUT sadly it may be a lot of other letter from a lot of other encodings. Can you spot an "â" near your tests or code ? It may help to track down the problem.

Answer (score -1):

following code worked for me

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```